# CurrentScreenImage not giving complete image of screen

Tags: front-end, user-interface

Running 12.0.0 on Windows 64, with dual monitors

When I give the following as input:

```
CurrentScreenImage[]
```

rather than seeing an image of the complete screens from both devices, I only see a full screen for the second monitor (a 1920x1200 device) but only somewhat less than half the vertical extent of the screen for the first monitor (a 1536x864 device) rather than the full screen).

Is there anyway to correct this, so that the entire first screen is captured as well?

Related to this question is the question: Is it possible to simultaneously set both the display number and the position on the display?  This is relevant since presently it is only the second of the two monitors that returns a full screen of data.  Currently, CurrenScreenImage[] only seems to be able to accept one argument, either the viewing window on the screen or the display (monitor) number.